# 2 links instead of 2-way link in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I need to draw and save to SVG a network with directed connections. I took example from here: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/251-network-with-node-size-based-on-edges-number.html

Here is my example with data:

```
library(igraph)

# create data:
links=data.frame(
    source=c("A","A", "A", "A", "A","J", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D","I"),
    target=c("B","B", "C", "D", "J","A","E", "F", "G", "H", "I","I")
)

# Turn it into igraph object
network <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, directed=T) 

# Count the number of degree for each node:
deg <- degree(network, mode="all")

# Plot

svg("c:\\temp\\network01.svg", 
    width = 7, height = 7, pointsize = 12)

plot(network, vertex.size=30, vertex.color=rgb(0.1,0.7,0.8,0.5) , edge.arrow.size = 0.7)


dev.off()
```

Result picture:
[image]

It's okay exept this part:

[image]

What I expected here - bigger link line length, 2 links instead of 1 2-way link. Something like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

BTW. Picture is different every time I generate it. Sometimes A <-> J link looks even worse:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the layout manually when the default arrangement is not good.  For example:

```
layout = matrix(c(0,0, 0,1, 0,-1,  -1,0, 1,0, 2,0, -0.5,-2,
                  0.5,-2,  -2,-0.5, -2,0.5), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
plot(network, vertex.size=30, vertex.color=rgb(0.1,0.7,0.8,0.5), 
     edge.arrow.size = 0.2, layout=layout)
```

Note that the order in which the coordinates are specified must atch the order of the nodes in the igraph object (which you can see using `lapply(network, names)`).

[image]

Alternatively, there are a wide number of automatic layout functions provided that you can try out to find a layout you like. `?layout_with_fr` provides a list of available layout functions.  For example:

```
plot(network, vertex.size=30, vertex.color=rgb(0.1,0.7,0.8,0.5),
     edge.arrow.size = 0.2, 
     layout=layout_with_sugiyama(network)$layout)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I like layout_with_kk one, looks good.